# How do I sort the output of SessionInfo() in R?

Tags: r, sorting

I want to sort the output of `sessionInfo()`. I tried doing it using `lapply()` but I am missing quite a few things.

For instance, when I tried this command:

```
lapply(sessionInfo(),function (x) {sort(names(x))})
```

I got:

```
$R.version
 [1] "arch"           "day"            "language"       "major"          "minor"          "month"         
 [7] "nickname"       "os"             "platform"       "status"         "svn rev"        "system"        
[13] "version.string" "year"          

$platform
NULL

$locale
NULL

$running
NULL

$basePkgs
NULL

$otherPkgs
 [1] "bit"               "bit64"             "boot"              "car"               "compare"          
 [6] "corrgram"          "corrplot"          "cowplot"           "debug"             "directlabels"     
[11] "dplyr"             "foreign"           "Formula"           "ggplot2"           "ggthemes"         
[16] "gmodels"           "hexbin"            "Hmisc"             "installr"          "knitr"            
[21] "lattice"           "lubridate"         "magrittr"          "maps"              "openxlsx"         
[26] "pastecs"           "plotly"            "plyr"              "psych"             "purrr"            
[31] "R2HTML"            "readr"             "readstata13"       "reshape2"          "ResourceSelection"
[36] "rJava"             "rmarkdown"         "sm"                "stringr"           "survival"         
[41] "tables"            "tibble"            "tidyr"             "tidyverse"         "tufte"            
[46] "tufterhandout"     "vcd"               "xlsxjars"          "xts"               "zoo"              

$loadedOnly
 [1] "acepack"      "assertthat"   "backports"    "base64enc"    "bitops"       "broom"        "caTools"     
 [8] "checkmate"    "class"        "cluster"      "codetools"    "colorspace"   "data.table"   "DBI"         
[15] "dendextend"   "DEoptimR"     "digest"       "diptest"      "evaluate"     "flexmix"      "foreach"     
[22] "fpc"          "gclus"        "gdata"        "gplots"       "gridExtra"    "gtable"       "gtools"      
[29] "haven"        "hms"          "htmlTable"    "htmltools"    "htmlwidgets"  "httr"         "iterators"   
[36] "jsonlite"     "kernlab"      "KernSmooth"   "latticeExtra" "lazyeval"     "lme4"         "lmtest"      
[43] "MASS"         "Matrix"       "MatrixModels" "mclust"       "mgcv"         "minqa"        "mnormt"      
[50] "modelr"       "modeltools"   "munsell"      "mvbutils"     "mvtnorm"      "nlme"         "nloptr"      
[57] "nnet"         "parallel"     "pbkrtest"     "prabclus"     "quadprog"     "quantreg"     "R6"          
[64] "RColorBrewer" "Rcpp"         "readxl"       "registry"     "robustbase"   "rpart"        "rprojroot"   
[71] "rvest"        "scales"       "seriation"    "SparseM"      "splines"      "stats4"       "stringi"     
[78] "tools"        "trimcluster"  "TSP"          "viridisLite"  "whisker"      "xml2"
```

We can see that there quite a few `NULL` fields. Plus, the output we get about `$R` (i.e. by running just `sessionInfo()`, is also missing.)

I tried another thing, just to see whether sorting one level deep into the list might show me information about `R.version, $platform, $locale, $running`

```
lapply(a,function (x) {lapply(x, function(x){sort(names(x))})})
```

This didn't help either. Can someone please help me? Sorted output is much better for scanning which packages are missing.

Comment: what info do you want from this? when you do `sessionInfo()` a print function displays only some of the information in special ways, see `utils:::print.sessionInfo`

Comment: @rawr - thanks for your help. I want the same output as `sessionInfo()`, except that the packages displayed be sorted. I got the latter part but lost the initial "header" (R version, platform locale etc.) that comes with `sessionInfo()`

Comment: the order is actually important, but if you really want it sorted, `si <- sessionInfo(); si[] <- lapply(si, function(x) if (is.list(x)) x[sort(names(x))] else sort(x)); si` should work

Comment: @rawr - Thanks. That works well. if you could post the answer, I can accept it. It will be great if you could walk me through how you did it. I tried executing your code without `ifelse`. i.e. `si <- sessionInfo(); si[sort(names(si))]`, and my screen gets bombarded with so much text. Could you please explain why this happens? I am beginner and not really sure.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
si <- sessionInfo()
si[] <- lapply(si, function(x) if (is.list(x)) x[sort(names(x))] else sort(x))
si

# R version 3.3.2 (2016-10-31)
# Platform: x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)
# Running under: OS X El Capitan 10.11.6
# 
# locale:
#   [1] en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8
# 
# attached base packages:
#   [1] base      datasets  graphics  grDevices methods   stats     utils    
# 
# loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
#   [1] tools_3.3.2
```

---

`si[sort(names(si))]` would work for a named list if the list elements are atomic. For example, a data frame:

```
str(as.list(mtcars)[sort(names(mtcars))])
# List of 11
# $ am  : num [1:32] 16.5 17 18.6 19.4 17 ...
# $ carb: num [1:32] 2.62 2.88 2.32 3.21 3.44 ...
# $ cyl : num [1:32] 4 4 1 1 2 1 4 2 2 4 ...
# $ disp: num [1:32] 6 6 4 6 8 6 8 4 4 6 ...
# ...
```

We cannot do this with a character vector:

```
letters[sort(names(letters))]
# character(0)
# Warning message:
# In is.na(x) : is.na() applied to non-(list or vector) of type 'NULL'
```

Unless the character vector was named

```
ll <- setNames(letters, letters)
ll[sort(names(ll))]
#   a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z 
# "a" "b" "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i" "j" "k" "l" "m" "n" "o" "p" "q" "r" "s" "t" "u" "v" "w" "x" "y" "z"
```

The problem is that `sessionInfo()` contains a list of both lists and character vectors

```
sapply(si, class)
# R.version    platform      locale     running    basePkgs  loadedOnly 
#    "list" "character" "character" "character" "character"      "list"
```

So we could sort the character vectors with just `sort`

```
sort(si$basePkgs)
# [1] "base"      "datasets"  "graphics"  "grDevices" "methods"   "stats"     "utils"
```

But not the lists

```
sort(si$loadedOnly)
# Error in sort.int(x, na.last = na.last, decreasing = decreasing, ...) : 
#   'x' must be atomic
```

To sort the lists, we can use the sorted names and index the list like this

```
(nn <- sort(names(si$loadedOnly)))
# [1] "tools"

si$loadedOnly[nn]
```

So we need the if-else to deal with both cases

```
lapply(si, function(x) if (is.list(x)) sort(names(x)) else sort(x))
# $R.version
# [1] "arch"           "day"            "language"       "major"          "minor"         
# [6] "month"          "nickname"       "os"             "platform"       "status"        
# [11] "svn rev"        "system"         "version.string" "year"          
# 
# $platform
# [1] "x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0 (64-bit)"
# 
# $locale
# [1] "en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8/C/en_US.UTF-8/en_US.UTF-8"
# 
# $running
# [1] "OS X El Capitan 10.11.6"
# 
# $basePkgs
# [1] "base"      "datasets"  "graphics"  "grDevices" "methods"   "stats"     "utils"    
# 
# $loadedOnly
# [1] "tools"
```

The final piece is the use of `[] <-` rather than simply `<-` to preserve the attributes of `si` in this case to keep the `class(si)`. Here we are using the function `[<-` instead of the usual `<-`

```
si <- sessionInfo()
si[] <- lapply(si, function(x) if (is.list(x)) x[sort(names(x))] else sort(x))
si
```

Compare to

```
si <- sessionInfo()
si <- lapply(si, function(x) if (is.list(x)) x[sort(names(x))] else sort(x))
si
```